Intento instalar Winehq en mi pc linux huyra, intente de varias formas y varias veces pero siempre salen errores similares
vengo siguiendo todos los pasos de este video:  -   de todas formas, este es el error que me sale al momento de intentar instalar con
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 winehq-stable : Depende: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0~bullseye-1)
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos


aplica sudo apt-get install --fix-missing y sudo apt-get install wine-stable
